# MSBuild output in a runtime created directory same as my build label version number

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol

I am using Cruisecontrol for continuous integration.

I am getting code from TFS, and using CruiseControl built in labeller "assemblyversionlabeller", and then building the code using msbuild.

Now my requirement is I want to take build output to a runtime created directory same as my build label. My labeller is below:

```
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
<build></build>
<revison><revision>
```

And output directory should be like this;

f:\Builds[version number]\Debug (this folder contains debug build)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Major>1</Major>
        <Minor>0</Minor>
        <Build></Build>
        <Revision></Revision>
    </PropertyGroup>           
    <Target Name="CreateDirectories">
        <MakeDir Directories="f:\builds$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)\Debug"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```